# You cannot call create unless the parent is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an iteration

```
      current_item = line_items.create(product_id: product_id, instruction: instruction)
      current_item.save
      attribute_values.each do |attribute|
        current_item.line_item_attributes.create(product_attribute_id: attribute)
      end
```

and it gives me an error on creating the attributes. When I print out `current_item` I get

```
#<LineItem id: nil, product_id: 1, cart_id: 36, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, quantity: 1, instruction: "", order_id: nil>
```

which from my understanding means it's not saved yet. How can I fix this?

After calling `create!` the error returned is:

```
Validation failed: Order must exist
```

the Order model is recently added with this migration:

```
class AddOrderToLineItem < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :line_items, :order, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

and `LineItem belongs_to :order`. The issue here is I want it to be blank, because in this case it doesn't belong to an order yet.

Comment: to debug use `create!`, not `create`

Comment: And use debugger or binding.pry and call current_item.valid? followed by current_item.errors in case the result is false.

Comment: I've updated my code!

Comment: please show the code of your model. Do you have any validations?

Comment: @tillmo I do not. Which is why I find it so strange, when I uncomment the belongs_to it works though.

Comment: sounds like belongs_to has changed its behaviour in Rails 5...